# What is the proper way to setup Live environment on Google Tag Manager?

Tags: google-analytics, installation, google-tag-manager

Using Google Tag Manager, I want to use the **Environments** feature.
While the Environments setup is pretty straightforward, there is a special case regarding the Live environment setup. More specifically, [documentation](https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/6311518?hl=en) mentions:

> **Note:** Every container is set up with a "Live" environment by default, which always points to the container version that is currently published. You don't need to define the Live environment.

Now, in order to setup GTM in my website for Live, I have 2 possible snippets: the "default" snippet (Which can be obtained by Admin > Install Google Tag Manager in my container) and the "Live" snippet (which can be obtained via Admin > Environments > "Live" > (Actions) Get Snippet).

The problem here is that the first script does not seem to map properly to the Live environment, as using it in a Lookup Table, maps to the default value.

On the other hand, the second script seems to be working properly. My concern is that it uses 2 additional parameters (`gtm_auth` and `gtm_preview`), and I am not sure if they should be defined to Live environment. Additionally, several blogs suggest the use of the first script on the Live environment.

My question - and concern is, which of the 2 scripts is the optimal to use in order to setup Live Environment in GTM, in terms of proper installation, usage and security?

Please consider that suggesting the usage of different containers is not an option.

Comment: So for the environments variable, it doesn't "return" anything if you're using Live. It will only return a value when you're using the environment snippet or the share preview link. Thus the behavior you're getting with the lookup table is correct and expected. I would suggest you using the non-environment snippet for live, as it doesn't give away anything extra.

Comment: Yes, that's the expected result. It isn't a bug. The environment variable is empty for "Live".

Comment: Can you be more specific regarding the value of Environments variable? Why is it empty in that case? I would expect that, Environment Name variable should return "Live", not nothing. Isn't it true?

Comment: Environment Name: Returns the user-provided name of the current environment, if the container request was made from an environment "Share Preview" link or from an environment snippet. For the built-in environments, it will return "Live", "Latest", or "Now Editing". In all other cases it returns an empty string. https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/7182738?hl=en&ref_topic=7182737&vid=0-1500790361317-1542725281860#utilities

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're experiencing is the expected behavior. As per [documentation](https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/7182738?hl=en&ref_topic=7182737&vid=0-1500790361317-1542725281860#utilities) the built-in `Environment` Variable is defined as follows:

> **Environment Name:** Returns the user-provided name of the current environment, if the container request was made from an environment
>   "Share Preview" link or from an environment snippet. For the built-in
>   environments, it will return "Live", "Latest", or "Now Editing". In
>   all other cases it returns an empty string.

In this case, when using the "Share Preview" or the snippet from Admin > Environments > "Live" > (Actions) Get Snippet will result in the variable to be populated.

When using the snippet from Admin > Install Google Tag Manager in my container, the variable will be empty since it isn't an environment snippet.

In terms of installation, I would suggest using the non-environment snippet version for live, as less information is shared publically (values from gtm_auth & env parameters)

Comment: Ok, the point is, I want to use the default snippet in order to avoid publishing gtm_auth and env parameters. Yet, I want to be able to distinguish Live from default values in a lookup table. I guess this can not be done with environment name in that case, am I right?

Comment: I'm guessing you're using default values for staging as a catch-all and wanted to use "Live" for only Live?

Comment: Not exactly the case, yet, I want to distinguish "Live" from default value.

Comment: I've been doing something similar by utilizing the "Page Hostname" variable in a lookup table.

Comment: I was thinking of the same thing, actually. Yet, I was searching if anything could be done with Environment Name variable exclusively. I highly doubt though this can be done that way.

Comment: I think the value/use case for Environments was meant for using the environment snippets for ease of testing.

Comment: This would make sense. I am not sure though if using the hostname would be a good alternative though. It seems to be doing the job, actually. But is it a good idea?

Comment: The only downside, as with all your information in GTM is that it is publically available. So if you put in a public IP or staging hostnames, people might try to access it if they get a hold of it.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest and the most secure approach to GTM Environments is:

- Use the 'default' GTM snippet, which can be obtained by "Admin" > "Install Google Tag Manager", for your production (aka Live) environment
- Use custom environments' snippets for other environments (e.g. Stage, Dev, Localhost) which can be obtained via "Admin" > "Environments" > "your_custom_env_name" > "Actions" > "Get Snippet"
- Use your custom Environments Names as Variables in Filters (i.e. Triggers used as Exceptions) and in Lookup tables (i.e. Custom Variables)
- Set production IDs as default value in Lookup Tables